# Data model for timeline event synchronisation

Tags: language-agnostic, data-modeling

I am looking for ideas on the data model for the following problem (and the proper CS terminology):

A (horizontal) "timeline" with several rows (A,B,C) contains "events" (1,2,3) width different durations (width) at different times (absolute x position or by delay "." after previous event):

```
A 1111....222222
B   33333
------------------
T 0123456789ABCDEF
```

(The rows are only interesting for graphical representation of overlapping/parallel "events", so they probably are not essential to the data model.)

Event duration may vary, affecting the whole timing:

```
A 11....222222
B   33333+3
------------------
T 0123456789ABCDEF
```

But let event 2 require events 1 and 3 to be finished, so the timing should look like this:

```
A 11....   222222
B   33333+3
------------------
T 0123456789ABCDEF
```

(let's ignore that the original delay at T=7 is now missing.)

Originally I thought I'd have to have some "elastic" synchronization elements, one for each row:

```
A 11....####222222
B   33333+3#
------------------
T 0123456789ABCDEF
```

Thus the original problem of how to model and sync the sync elements in the two different "rows". But, as established above, this is only a matter of graphical/parallel representation.

Rather, the sync is a condition that could be "attached" to event 2, modifiying or determining its beginning.
If an event "has" a condition, it will not have an absolute or relative start time. Its start can only be determined at the ends of the "linked" events (1 and 3).

So, given (a list of) some events with variable duration and either an absolute start time or a delay relative to another event's end, how could the condition "events 1 and 3 ended" be modelled to determine the start of "event 2"?

(I will prototype this in JavaScript and eventually implement in C/C++, so any sample code provided should not use high-level data types or libraries.)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an object that I would call a `TimeFrame`. The object would have the attributes `duration`, `link` and `type`, where `link` can be a precise time or a link to another `TimeFrame` and `type` accounts for the kind of `link`. For instance, a given `TimeFrame` that starts at a known time would have that time as its `link` attribute and the `type` would be `TIME`. A `TimeFrame` that is linked to the end of another would have that other `TimeFrame` as its `link` attribute and `START-END` as its `type` and so on.

Using the combination between `link` and `type` you could also support other types of links such as `START-START`, `END-START` or `END-END`.

**UPDATE**

Also, in order to allow some time interval between say, the end of a `TimeFrame` and the start of the next, one can add the attribute `lag`, which represents any delay between events. So, for instance if `tf1` and `tf2` are `TimeFrames` such that `tf2` must start `5` time units after the end of `tf1` the attributes of `tf2` would be `link = tf1`, `type = START-END`, `duration = <something>` and `lag = 5`. Note also that the `lag` could be negative, which would extend the expressiveness of the model to a broad range of relationships.

Answer (score 1):

While @Leandro Caniglia nicely rephrased my question into an Object and Attributes, essentially, I see two options:

1. the whole list of "events" needs to be evaluated at "condition" (start/end) to check dependent "events".
2. adding a "link" to a "parent" also creates a link to the "child" (no need to evaluate all pending event's links).

Also:

- The "link" property needs to be a List or Array to be able hold several references (e.g. 2:[1,3]).
- Analogous to the link property start_me_on_condition a stop_me_on_condition association may be desirable (see Leandro's suggestion of `type`, it would need to be extended to support multiple links+type)
- An independet delay "event" might be more practical than a `lag` property.